# Button cannot click

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore

After i change the code like this, the button cannot be clicked. Before i change, the button can be clicked. By the way, where is my mistake?

Code :

```
    buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String getBarcode = scanBarcodeEditText.getText().toString().trim();

            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getBarcode)) {
                scanBarcodeEditText.setError("Please enter barcode");
            } else {
                checkBarcode(getBarcode);
            }
        }
    });

private void checkBarcode(final String barcode) {
    collectionReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                    if (queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("barCode") != null) {
                        collectionReference.document(queryDocumentSnapshot.getId()).update("productQuantity", FieldValue.increment(1).toString());
                        // Intent to another activity
                    } else {
                       // Intent to another activity
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How you indetified that button click is not working? Did you added any logs there?

Comment: What do you mean through "the button cannot be clicked"? Do you have an error? Please also respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: when i toast some text, button click can be clicked. But when i set intent, button click is cannot move to another activity. The code same like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code working fine I have tested with printing toast and method as well.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button buttonNext;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);

        buttonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "NextClicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //checkBarcode("123");
                String getBarcode = scanBarcodeEditText.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(getBarcode)) {
                    scanBarcodeEditText.setError("Please enter barcode");
                } else {
                    checkBarcode(getBarcode);
                }
            }
        });
    }


    private void checkBarcode(final String barcode) {

        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Method Call", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        collectionReference.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot queryDocumentSnapshot : task.getResult()) {
                        if (queryDocumentSnapshot.getString("barCode") != null) {
                            collectionReference.document(queryDocumentSnapshot.getId()).update("productQuantity", FieldValue.increment(1).toString());
                            // Intent to another activity
                        } else {
                            // Intent to another activity
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i think my algorithm firestore code is wrong..